What is this metal loop keeping me from removing screw from drywall?
I took a mirror off the bathroom wall that had been held up by the bracket pictured below. Most of the brackets were easy to remove from the wall, but for 2 of the 6 brackets the screw is just spinning endlessly when I try to unscrew it. I tried to lightly pull it out, but stopped when I saw a loop of metal come out of the wall above the screw (seen in second picture below). I'm not sure what I'm looking at, and would like to know:

What is this metal loop?
How do I remove the screw from the wall with minimal damage?




Your location might help.  It looks like a covered/insulated wire, which might be concerning.  It might also be part of a toggle bolt, since the wall there looks empty(no stud/blocks to hold a screw).  If a toggle bolt, snip/cut the screw head off and push back in the wall.

Have you tried holding the loop (with pliers) while trying to undo the bolt? My gut is that it’s just a toggle, and will fall happily into the wall when detached.

If location helps, this is a house built in the 1960s in New England. And it's exposed metal without any plastic coating so I don't think it's covered / insulated.

There might be a "toggle" on the back side of the screw. This is a spring-loaded wing-like thing. If you pull lightly on the screw while turning it that'll provide a bit of friction to hold the whatever-it-is behind the wall in place. This will prevent the thing from spinning so that you can unscrew.
Or: get a pair of diagonal cutters or other steel-cutting tool and simply cut the screw. Let the inside part fall into the wall. (That's what'll happen anyway when the toggle portion is fully unscrewed, if that's what's in there.)
